# How to use a 2D array in the ImHex pattern language?

Tags: imhex-pattern-language

As part of a larger C program I write a 2D float array to a binary file. To check the file I want to use ImHex's powerful pattern editor.
The [language documentation](https://docs.werwolv.net/pattern-language/) doesn't specify a 2D array type.
I know I could use `float array[width*hight];` But that doesn't help much to find the correct floating point value in the array.
Is there another workaround to use 2D arrays in the ImHex pattern language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the best way to do this is by using a custom type that contains an array and then creating an array out of that.

```
struct MyArray {
    float array[parent.width]
};

struct SomeType {
    u32 width, height;
    MyArray array[height];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for writing this hex editor and pattern language btw.!  It's a really amazing tool..